# How to connect to MySQL database from other host using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to connect to MySQL using PHP, but database is on a other host , I can't do It correctly.

I'm useing this code. Error is in this line:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("hostex.lt","myInfo","pass","myInfoo");
```

"hostex.lt". Database is in hostex.lt, phpMyAdmin: myadmin.hostex.lt I've tried It but It always print `error:error:error:error:error:error:error:error:error:error:`

This code working in other project where I use localhost, so here is problem.

```
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into game (taskai, userName) VALUE (?,?) ")) {
    if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    } else {
    //    printf(" ", $mysqli->character_set_name());
    }


    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $score, $name);
      // $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

       $stmt->execute();

       if ($stmt->error != '') {
           echo ' error:'.$stmt->error;
       } else {
           echo 'success';
       }
       $stmt->close();
    } else {
       echo 'error:'.$mysqli->error;
    }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

**UPDATE**

I've got this error:

[image: error]

Comment: FTP is not a database ... and a database can't really be "on a ftp". please clarify.

Comment: Nevermind, I just need to know what and how to use instead of "localhost" If I'm useing hostex.lt

Comment: Add this to the top of your PHP file: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`. Maybe some error messages will shed light.

Comment: I edited my question with screenshot of error

Comment: Have you allowed remote access to your database, white listing your IP?

Comment: You say your database is on 'hostex.lt', but you connect to 'myadmin.hostex.lt' on your screenshot. Try the database hostname. And btw, you can copy&paste the text, no need for screenshots.

Comment: @HarryDenley I don't know how to allow remote access

Comment: Ensure your host and credentials are correct. You will also need to ensure that you have a user on the remote MySQL database which is configured to allow your client to connect, e.g. 'username'@'89.345.3.45' (of course, replacing the example IP with the client IP)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I've tried hostex.lt, myadmin.hostex.lt, but unsuccessfully in both cases.

Comment: @Stanyer I need to create user as you said in database?

Comment: @Infinity use 'hostex.lt' and post the error message. I'm pretty sure that your database doesn't allow access from your host. You can add a user with permissions from your PHP host under Privileges in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: That's right. So say for example the IP of your client (the server connecting to the external database) is 1.2.3.4, you need to create a MySQL user on the remote database which authorizes a connection from 1.2.3.4 - e.g. `'dbuser'@'1.2.3.4'`. You will then use that user to connect to the database.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider everything the same, only first line: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'myDbName'@'www.ftpDomainName.lt' (using password: YES) `

Comment: Since hostex.lt is a shared hosting it does not allow remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL only allows access from localhost, if you want to access it from a different host you have to allow it explicitly.

Log into PHPMyAdmin, go to Privileges, add a user 'myDbName'@'www.ftpDomainName.lt' (the host part after the @ is important) and give it access to your database.

If you don't have access to the Privileges section in your PHPMyAdmin you will have to contact the hoster of your database.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be a PHP problem *per se*, but most probably something on the database server that is blocking the connection.

Try the following in this order, running your code after each step:

**New MySQL user**

- Add a new database user via PHPMyAdmin.
- Go to the Privileges and then add user.
- The Host can be set to a '%' (wildcard - allows all servers access. This is less secure but can be tightened up later).
- Fill in a username and password which you will then use in the PHP
  code.
- Retry your code.

**Database Server**

On the database server ask the sysadmin to edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf (assumption is that this is a Linux machine with the my.cnf stored at this location -- your sysadmin will know how to find the correct file).

- Comment out the sections 'bind-address = 127.0.0.1' and  'skip-networking' (if its there.) using a # character at the start of the line.
- Save the file
- Restart the MySQL service (service mysql restart).
- Retry your code

**Firewall**

If the above steps haven't worked, then most likely a firewall is blocking the connection.

- On the server, allow port 3306 to accept incoming connections
- If there is a shared firewall device or the cloud hosting partner (eg. AWS) has a firewall, allow port 3306
- Retry your code.

*Note that if the sysadmin of the MySQL server does not want to open the port on the firewall or enable external connections to the database, there is not a lot you can do*